Filtering by the 'from' field in Stripe Connect's 'Payments' Embedded Component
I want to see all payments made by a specific customer, is there any way to enable filtering by the 'from' field in Stripe Connect's 'Payments' embedded component described here?
If there isn't then there should definitely be, this is pretty much the most standard field to filter on.
I tried looking at the stripe docs and the api reference here to no avail.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Filter From field is not supported by the embedded connect component.

I'd recommend writing to Stripe Support as as feature request.
